# What does the word 'does' in the second part refer to?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentene, what does the word 'does' in the second part refer to?

> The salt does not lose ammonia in dry air, but does so very slowly in moist air.

Comment: It's a verb phrase reduction. "Does" combines with "so" and "does so" is understood as "loses ammonia".

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the subject "the salt":

> *The salt* does not lose ammonia in dry air, but **the salt** does **lose ammonia** very slowly in moist air.

Comment: It is used to avoid repetition a full verb, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Instead of repeating the subject ("the salt"), people normally just say the verb in this case ("does" in your case). Yes, it is used to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Is it used instead of the verb 'lose'?

Comment: Yes, it is the *emphatic* of "lose". One usually uses "does" in the negation: "The salt **does not** *lose* ammonia"; however, one could use the emphatic without negation here: "The salt **does** *lose* ammonia." In this case, we could also say: "The salt **does not lose** ammonia in dry air, but **loses** ammonia very slowly in moist air." One could also say, "The salt **does not lose** ammonia in dry air, but **does lose** ammonia in moist air."

Answer (score 0):

"Does" is simply part of the negation in the first clause and is used in the second clause to emphasize the fact that there's a distinction between dry and moist air.